# Formula for roots of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, roots

For a quadratic polynomial there exists a formula for its roots. I read that similarly for polynomials of degree 3 and 4 there also exists such a formula but that no such formulas exist for polynomials of degree 5 or higher.

Does there exist a proof that no such formulas for $\ge 5$ can exist or is it that they have not been found yet?

Comment: Yes, such a proof exists, as answered by Jared. It was proven by the Norwegian mathematician Niels Henrik Abel (1802-1829).

Comment: Actually, formulas do exist for _some- but-not-all_ polynomials of degree 5-or-higher. This depends on the Galois group of the polynomial. This is part of Galois Theory; you calculate the Galois group and decide if it is solvable, I believe.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that, even though no general formula exists (i.e. for all possible solutions), this does not mean to say that the solutions themselves do not exist?

Comment: @pbs, all this means there is *no general solution by means of radicals* (say, as in the quadratic, cubic or quartic case) of a quintic equation.

Comment: See the book [Abel's Proof](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/abels-proof) by Peter Pesic.

Answer (score 4):

There is a proof, and it is quite beautiful.  The result is known as the [Abel-Ruffini Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel-Ruffini_theorem), and the standard proof of this fact uses Galois theory and the fact that the alternating group on $n\ge 5$ symbols is not solvable.  This wasn't the original proof, but it is the most elegant.  The link provided contains a brief outline of the proof based on Galois's ideas.

Comment: The original proof is not that bad. http://www.math.caltech.edu/~jimlb/abel.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There does exists a proof that polynomials with degree greater than 4 cannot be solved with radicals, the proof relies heavily on Galois theory. See for example [here](http://documents.kenyon.edu/math/FranzSenEx2010.pdf).